# Fetch the Product of Shopware 6

Tags: javascript, fetch, shopware6, shopware6-api

I am using this endpoint (http://localhost/store-api/product/{productId}) to fetch the specific product. But when I send the request it returns the best variant product. I want the main products, not the variant product how can I fetch that?

[API reference](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/8faf525d8ec07-fetch-a-single-product)

I tried to this by passing product id, parentproduct id in the place of productID in the endpoint but I am unable to get the main product with different varriant.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPYMG.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't retrieve the parent product record via the store-api, as it is not a purchasable item.

The parent merely acts as glue for the variants which are the actual  goods. Furthermore it exists as a means to allow the variants to possibly inherit one and the same value. The parent passing on its values as inheritance is also the reason why it should not be accessed directly.

If the parent record would be made available to fetch via the store-api, it could lead to faulty purchases, that's why it will always return a variant instead.

You may use the [admin-api](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/ZG9jOjEyMzA4NTQ4-reading-entities) if you must retrieve the raw data of the parent.

Comment: Hey, @dneustadt I have four different images in the product but when I fetch the product it only gives one image. Then, how can I fetch that four different images?

Comment: Depends on how the variant was persisted with their respective `media` assignments. Was it persisted with its own images? Then it won't inherit the images from the parent. Either remove the one image assigned to the variant, to enable inheriting all media from the parent, or alternatively add the missing media assignments to the variant directly.

Comment: Is there any way to get all the images of the product without changing the variant product properties or anything?

Comment: If it has to be exposed via an endpoint of the store-api you'll have to write an extension. One possible approach would be to [add a custom route](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/store-api/add-store-api-route). Within the controller for the route you can inject `product.repository`, which will allow you to fetch the data of the parent and to then return it in the response.

Comment: I've installed the PWA of shopware 6 locally and in the PWA the image of the product is showing. I think the PWA is also using an endpoint to get the details of the product. Then how can I get that using endpoint? I have attached the screenshot of the product detail in the main question. Please see that image.